# Asymptotic formula for cot(x).

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

So I'm asked to pick such $A$ and $B$ that when $x$ approaches $0,$

$$\cot(x) = (1 + Ax^2)/(x + Bx^2)  +  O(x^5)$$[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPnkU.png)

I have no idea how to do that. Any help appreciated!

Comment: And what did you find?

Comment: What’s your thinking?

Comment: This cannot be the question : read it again

Answer (score 0):

The expression in the image seems to be
$$
\text{ctg}\,x=\frac{1+Ax^2}{x+Bx^{\color{red}{3}}}+O(x^5). \tag{1}
$$
The series expansion at $x=0$ of the LHS of $(1)$ [gives](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=series+cot%28x%29)
$$
\text{ctg}\,x=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{3}-\frac{x^3}{45}+O(x^5), \tag{2}
$$
whereas for the RHS it yields
\begin{align}
\frac{1+Ax^2}{x+Bx^3}&=\frac{1}{x}(1+Ax^2)(1-Bx^2+B^2x^4+O(x^6)) \\
&=\frac{1}{x}+(A-B)x+(B^2-AB)x^3+O(x^5). \tag{3}
\end{align}
Equating coefficients of equal powers of $x$ we obtain the system of equations
$$
\begin{cases}
A-B=-\frac{1}{3}, \\
B^2-AB=-\frac{1}{45},
\end{cases} \tag{4}
$$
the solution of which is
$$
(A,B)=\left(-\frac{2}{5},-\frac{1}{15}\right). \tag{5}
$$